# prove that a function is continuously differentiable everywhere

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prove a function is continuously differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222396/prove-a-function-is-continuously-differentiable)

$f(x,y) =\begin{cases}\arctan(y/x) & x\neq 0\\ \pi/2 & x=0,y>0\\-\pi/2 & x=0,y<0.\end{cases}$

$f$ is defined on $\Bbb R^2\smallsetminus\{(0,0)\}.$

Show that $f$ is continuously differentiable on all of its domain.

Also use implicit function to show the above proof again.

Thanks!