# Using implicit function theorem, $f(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [prove a function is continuously differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/222396/prove-a-function-is-continuously-differentiable)

Use implicit function theorem to prove the following function is continuously differentiable

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) & x\neq 0
\\ π/2 & x=0,\ y>0
\\ −π/2 & x=0,\ y<0\end{cases}$$
where $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,\ 0)\}$.

How can I use implicit function theorem to prove this? I know how to directly prove it but don't really know how to prove this with IFT. any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/222396

Comment: The two current close votes are saying that it is a duplicate of an already closed question...